# google cloud app engine deploy failed

Tags: google-app-engine

I following the google cloud console right side tutorial to deploy a ruby project, after clone the demo source code the try to using command `gcloud app deploy --project fireflywytwyt` to deploy, it throw following error to me(Unnecessary logs is omitted):

```
...
8820c09c846d: Image already exists
64fc2a97cff9: Image already exists
43f58141118b: Image already exists
575d6bde5efe: Image already exists
272ffca85019: Image already exists
90a62e26e551: Image already exists
a51047f764d0: Image already exists
2c8496abe349: Image already exists
6e04b82f3d6e: Image already exists
latest: digest: sha256:406115ccfa93d7cef120b2683f75c9f5b3821d8a11b8afbca7781240c293313e size: 72372
DONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] The user fireflywytwyt@appspot.gserviceaccount.com must have permission to read the image at us.gcr.io/fireflywytwyt/appengine/def
ault.20161124t144728:latest
```

Please notice the error:

`The user fireflywytwyt@appspot.gserviceaccount.com must have permission to read the image at us.gcr.io/fireflywytwyt/appengine/def`

It seems my account cannot access the docker registry, how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give the service user (in your case *fireflywytwyt@appspot.gserviceaccount.com* ) Editor role. To do this

- Open the IAM & Admin page in the Cloud Platform Console.
- Select your project and click Continue.
- Click Add member.
- Enter the email address of the service account, select an **Editor** role  and click Add.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still not work, I add `fireflywytwyt@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as a `project owner`(maybe highest permission), but still same problem

Comment: Try Editor role , there is a bug with permissions

Comment: For me the editor role had already been assigned, however the account was missing a key. It worked after generating that on the service account page.

Comment: Can confirm that this answer worked for us. Make sure to add the service account in IAM as user with project editor permissions.

Comment: This approach would give way more permissions than needed to the service account user.

Answer (score -4):

Give your Service Account appropriate permissions:

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} \
--member serviceAccount:codelab@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/owner

Comment: Downvote, because this would give the service account owner rights in the project, which can cause a lot of damage.